# athena query to collapse sparse matrix / columnar data

Tags: sparse-matrix, parquet, amazon-athena

Suppose I have the following table `table1` in Amazon Athena (technically, in Glue):

```
torg, foo, bar, x1, x2, x3, baz
-------------------------------
t1, 1, NULL,   NULL, NULL, NULL, goober
t2, 1, NULL,   NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL  -- want to ignore this row entirely, even though foo=1
t3, 1, tronic, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
...
t4, 2, NULL,   NULL, NULL, NULL, horse
t4, 2, zebra,  NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
...
```

Is there an Athena query that can `group by` `foo` (in this example `foo=1`), but ignoring `NULL` column values for each row, such that a result would look like?

```
foo, bar, baz
----------------
1, tronic, goober
```

For context, I am writing the as partitioned parquet to S3 at different times.  It's wonderful using Athena to query this data, but I'm having a hard time envisioning if Athena is the right place to "collapse" this columnar data, into more "row-wise" data grouped by a particular column (or set of columns).

While I will likely further work with this data in pandas, and could "collapse" it there, I was hoping there might be a query pattern in Athena.  Or perhaps I'm thinking about this entirely wrong...

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one value per group then you can use `max` (or `min`) and `group by`:

```sql
WITH dataset(foo,bar, baz) AS (
   VALUES 
    (1,NULL,'tronic'),
    (1,'goober',NULL),
    (1,NULL, NULL)
 ) 
 
SELECT foo, max(bar) bar, max(baz) baz
FROM dataset
GROUP BY foo
```

Output:

| foo | bar | baz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | goober | tronic |